# Sending dynamic parameters to the server where numbers may also vary

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, post

I have a number of parameters in an array. These number of parameters are not fixed. They can be 2, 3 or sometimes even 10.

```
[["tag1", "value1"], ["tag2", "value2"], ["tag3", "value3"]] ...
```

I want to send all these parameters to server (php) in my jquery load function
I am using

```
$("#LB").load("serverSideFile.php", {
    //parameters for eg {name: "value"}
});
```

That is where I want to add all the parameters. using for loop? Please help me.

As some of the parameters may have many characters I want to send them using post method. Hence I am avoiding appending all of them in the url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to iterate over them and assign them to an object (though it would be better to jsut put them in an object instead of an array in the first place).

```
var data = {},
    arr = [["tag1", "value1"], ["tag2", "value2"], ["tag3", "value3"]];

for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
   var key = arr[i][0],
       value = arr[i][1];

   data[key] = value;
}

$("#LB").load("serverSideFile.php", data);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. I followed your advice and converted that array conversion to object.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myData = [["tag1", "value1"], ["tag2", "value2"], ["tag3", "value3"]];    

var requestData = {};

$.each(myData, function(i, item) {
   requestData[item[0]] = item[1];
});

$("#LB").load("serverSideFile.php", requestData);
```